# Difference between keyup and afterkeydown events of knockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Can anybody please explain me the exact difference between `input`, `keyup`, `keypress` and `afterkeydown` events parameters for the value binding in `knockoutJS` ?I'm confused from reading about these from [link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html), quoting the same below:

> If your **value** binding also includes a parameter called **valueUpdate**, this defines additional browser events KO should use to detect changes besides the change event. The following string values are the most commonly useful choices:
>
> **input** - updates your view model when the value of an  or  element changes. Note that this event is only raised by reasonably modern browsers (e.g., IE 9+).
>
> **keyup** - updates your view model when the user releases a key
>
> **keypress** - updates your view model when the user has typed a key. Unlike keyup, this updates repeatedly while the user holds a key down
>
> **afterkeydown** - updates your view model as soon as the user begins typing a character. This works by catching the browser’s **keydown** event and handling the event asynchronously. This does not work in some mobile browsers.

Correct me if, I'm wrong the `input` event is happens once the user is finished typing the `text` in the `textbox` and the cursor is not still in the textbox. The `keypress` event is used to detect cases when the key is pressed for a long time, the event is fired and the characters are recorded proportional to the time of pressing.The `keypress` is high level event as compared to `keyup` and `keydown`.

The definitions of **keypup** and **afterkeydown** are what I find confusing and want to know particular use cases of these two, in context to valueUpdate binding.